# Excel VBA error 3704 operation not allowed when object is closed at ADODB.Recordset.AddNew

Tags: sql-server-2008, vba, excel

Please forgive the sloppy coding, but I was thrown onto a project to get data from a spreadsheet to SQL server and the deadline has been missed. I was able to initial get my first dataswipe using a SELECT statement, but I can't seem to switch it over to an UPDATE.

Here's the code.  I get the runtime error 3704 operation not allowed when object is closed at the line rstRecordset.AddNew

```
Public cnnConn As ADODB.Connection
Public rstRecordset As ADODB.Recordset
Public cmdCommand As ADODB.Command
Public Const Server As String = "datguy"
Public SQLQuery As String
Option Explicit

Sub testupinsertupdate()

Dim wkb As Workbook
Dim wks As Worksheet
Dim sel As Range
Set wkb = ActiveWorkbook
Set wks = Sheets(1)
Set sel = Selection

With wks

'Declaration unit

Dim dataitem As String
Dim yr As Integer
Dim yrmax As Integer
Dim rxcount As Integer
Dim row As Integer
Dim col As String
Dim cleanup As String
Dim sqlrxcount As String

dataitem = .Range("B3").Value
yr = 6 'data only needs to go back to 2006
yrmax = .Range("C7").End(xlToRight).row + yr 'declarative count to the Right-Of-File
rxcount = 7
row = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row 'declarative count to EOF
col = .Range("C6").End(xlToRight).Column
cleanup = "Data Unavailable"
sqlrxcount = .Range("A" & rxcount).Value

Set cnnConn = New ADODB.Connection
cnnConn.ConnectionString = "driver={SQL Server};server=" & Server & ";database=database;Trusted_Connection=Yes"
cnnConn.ConnectionTimeout = 800
cnnConn.Open

For rxcount = 7 To row
    Set cmdCommand = New ADODB.Command
    Set cmdCommand.ActiveConnection = cnnConn
        With cmdCommand
            .CommandTimeout = 0
            .CommandText = "UPDATE table SET " & dataitem & " = '" & Cells(col).Value & "' WHERE RX_ID = '" & sqlrxcount & "'"
            .CommandType = adCmdText
            .Execute
            Debug.Print cmdCommand.State
        End With
        Debug.Print cmdCommand.State
    Set rstRecordset = New ADODB.Recordset
    Set rstRecordset.ActiveConnection = cnnConn
    rstRecordset.Open cmdCommand, , adOpenStatic, adLockBatchOptimistic
    col = ("C" & rxcount)
     For yr = 6 To yrmax

        rstRecordset.AddNew '*** error pops!
        rstRecordset.Fields("RX_ID") = Range("A" & rxcount).Value
        rstRecordset.Fields("YEAR_REPORTED") = yr + 2000
        If Range(col).Value = cleanup Then
            rstRecordset.Fields(dataitem) = Null
        Else: rstRecordset.Fields(dataitem) = Range(col).Value
        End If

        'debug line to show results
        Debug.Print Range("A" & rxcount).Value, yr + 2000, Range(col).Value
        col = Range(col).Offset(0, 1).Address

    Next yr

Next rxcount

rstRecordset.UpdateBatch
rstRecordset.Close

cnnConn.Close


End With

End Sub
```

I don't feel like I'm doing the operations in order, but I'm just trying to get the initial load and then will worry about maintenance later.  Why isn't the object(I assume this is the recordset) open when it was opened three lines before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are attempting to open a recordset based on an update not a select
  rstRecordset.Open cmdCommand, , adOpenStatic, adLockBatchOptimistic
should be something like
  rstRecordset.Open "select * from table",cnnconn, adOpenStatic, adLockBatchOptimistic

Comment: To be fair, I should have deleted this question as it's no longer my problem (moved to a new company/position).  I believe your answer would have pointed me in the right direction in context.